telegram doesn't show white spaces correctly
I create a text in Python, and it displays correctly in its true shape in the terminal. However, when I use the Telegram API to send it to my channel, the white space sizes are not shown correctly. Here is a picture of the text in the terminal, and the other one is in Telegram.
I use this Python code to generate the results:
for name, price in prices:
      text += f"{name:<20} {price}\n"
print(text)



I tried using the U+00A0 character, but it didn't solve the problem.

اگه میخوای متن فارسی نشون بدی جای متن ها در تلگرام کاملا بهم میریزه و هیچ راه حلی هم براش وجود نداره. گشتم نبود نگرد نیست داداش

If you are using english language You can use prettytable library in python to create a perfect table that works inside <code> or <pre> tags.

Terminals typically use monospaced fonts in which every character take up the same space, while Telegram uses a variable width font in which character size is adjusted for readability. For instance, you can see how Mill takes the same space as Gol in your example, even though it's one less character.
You can use the markdown syntax for code blocks (wrapping in ```) in your telegram bot to achieve the same effect.

i used  instead and finally it worked.
